# How do i use an array to represent a form, to show and hide forms in VB

Tags: vb.net

I want to use a array to help me switch between forms in a quiz that i have to create for a school assignment. When a question is correct it shows the correct form. I am using one button to go to the next form. There are 20 questions each with its own form. This is what i need:

```
   Private Sub btnNext_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnNext.Click
    Me.Hide()
    arrayforms(count).Show()
```

Thanks

Comment: To keep this simple, you need a main form to handle all the others. If you use `ShowDialog` instead of `Show` the parent will freeze until the child form is closed

Answer (score 0):

First Collect all of your questionary forms into Array. Name your questionary forms as "Questionary1", "Questionary2" something like that, or set tag to you forms. Then find your form by index and create an instance and ShowDialog, that's it. Try following code.

```
Public Class Form1
    Private forms(20) As Type

    Private Sub Button1_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
        Dim yourFormIndex = 3
        Dim frm As Form = Activator.CreateInstance(forms(yourFormIndex))
        frm.ShowDialog()
    End Sub

    Private Sub Form1_Load(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
        Dim myAssembly As System.Reflection.Assembly = System.Reflection.Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly()
        Dim types As Type() = myAssembly.GetTypes()
        Dim index As Integer = 1

        For Each myType As Object In types

            If myType.BaseType.FullName.ToString.ToUpper = "SYSTEM.WINDOWS.FORMS.FORM" Then
                If (myType.Name.ToString.StartsWith("Questionary")) Then
                    forms(index) = myType
                    index = index + 1
                End If
            End If
        Next
    End Sub
End Class
```